# how to make a DSL for checking source code using xtext

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I am currently starting to make a program to check the code of a custom language using xtext in eclipse.
This is a textual langaue with certain syntax and certain formats for certain classes.

I wanted to ask if thier is any documentation on something similar or some papers that outline code checking or code checking in xtext using a DSL.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "code checking"? Xtext allows to create validators (see [the documentation here](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#validation)) that can be used to validate a program; does it suit your needs?

Comment: yes this is exactally what im looking for. @EmmanuelChebbi

Comment: I also want to add that i want to develop validation for a language that has already been developed. How would i go about this, the language is pretty small and its just a set of classes but i dont want to implement these features in xtext i just want to develop validation for this. @EmmanuelChebbi

Comment: Xtext should have generated a `MyLanguageValidator` class in your project's `src` folder (replace *MyLanguage* by the actual name of your language); you can write your validation rules there. If it doesn't exist you'll have to create the class manually and create a `bindMyLanguageAdapter()` method in `MyLanguageRuntimeModule` that returns this class. If you have to support validation outside of Xtext, you can still write a custom validator in plain Java/Xtend then use it in your Xtext validator.

Comment: yes this clears up a lot just new to xtext. I went through the tutorials too but i was confused as a lot of them used examples from languages they implemented using xtext but im not doing that. Im just implementing the validation for a language. The mylanguagevalidator did not exist in my src but i have done that and started on some validation code. Thank you. @EmmanuelChebbi